# Object property is undefined

Tags: javascript, object, gulp

I don't know if I'm missing something here, but for some reason a configuration object I create is always undefined upon using:

**gulpfile.config.js**

```
var config = {
    src_path: "Client/"
};
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var config = require("./gulpfile.config.js");

gulp.task("test", function() {
    util.log(config.src_path); // results in 'undefined'
});
```

Do objects have to be initialized within the scope of a gulp task or is there something wrong with the object declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `module.exports` to your `gulpfile.config.js`, like so

```
# gulpfile.config.js
var config = {
    src_path: "Client/"
};

module.exports = config
```

[module.exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) is the object that's returned as the result of a `require` call.

Answer (score 0):

It *does,* indeed, look to me like you are redefining that variable, probably causing it to have the value `true`.  Use the browser's JavaScript-console to be sure.

Comment: It looks like that because the OP has put all code into one block. If you look closely, they are in different files (denoted by the `# gulpfile.js`)

Comment: Yes... but as I read it *(perhaps incorrectly)* here's the conflict:  first, the file is "required," setting the value of `config`  But then, the same variable, `config`, is set to the return-value of the `require()`, thereby replacing it.

Comment: `config` variables are defined in separate modules using CommonJS syntax. They don't conflict :)